# Code folding (#pragma region) in Qt creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, pragma, code-folding

Is there something similar to explicit code regions for folding in Qt Creator:

```
#pragma region Region_1
void Test() {}
void Test2() {}
void Test3() {}
#pragma endregion Region_1
```

I can see [folding for logical](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/9a5a7) code blocks, but do not know how to explicitly set such a block. My version of Qt Creator is 2.4.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Currently not.](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTCREATORBUG-5170)

I think it is better to structure your code by using code anyways. The regions as also found in C# are imho a bad substitute for proper structuring and keeping things maintainable.

Comment: The humble opinion is the solicited opinion... IMO

Comment: @DaveCausey: My favourite dictionaries do not translate "solicitied" to something that makes sense in this context. Does it mean "the crowd's opinion"?

Comment: Solicited = requested in this context. Just being silly. I spent some time trying to find an answer to a similar question and there seems to be a lot of principled resistance to this practice. While I tend to agree, I have found outliners to be a helpful tool for breaking down pre-existing complexity in third party code when significant refactoring is not an immediate option.

Comment: So many reasons to do manual block folding... for example, folding across multiple blocks rather than just folding codes inside a pair of curly parenthesis.

Comment: And the folding algorithm in the editor is not easy, since the code can be complex.  `#ifdef` exists, many places, which can even destroy the pairing of curly parenthesis.  Current Qt editor code can not even handle the `#if 0 #else #endif` case.

Comment: @RobinHsu: Most of well structured code does not have multiple blocks that are so large that you want to fold them.

Comment: By folding codes, it's easier to read codes.  It's the reader's freedom to fold from anywhere to anywhere...  For example, if there are so many small functions, and I know I already understand them, I would like to fold them, so they will not affect my reading/editing.

Comment: @RobinHsu: The problem with this is that there is no clear definition of where to cut the line. Your folds might not equal a fellow programmer's folds, and suddenly all the code get's tainted with folds, checked into your version control system. If code is written in a readable, you do not have to look up functions permanently; and you can use your editor's navigation facilities to jump to functions or lines. Personally, I find folded code harder to read, because it's suddenly invisible, and I have to click here and there to make it visible again. This boils down to a zero sum at best.

Comment: It might be. But if you've ever seen a big C++ project, there are some code blocks that are absolutely required, yet not foldable and impact readability. For example: static members definitions and initialization. My embedded code has a lot of static members, they all have to be initialized in consistent blocks, yet that's a wall of (unfoldable) text beside methods. BTW, they can't be moved outside the main context.

Comment: @Harry: Personally, if I find code hard to read, I try to counter that by improving the readability by different means, e.g. refactoring such that the class declaration becomes smaller. Also, I find it helps a lot to have a certain order within the class declarations, e.g. constants and statics first, public first. One thing I really like in C++ is the way you declare visibility, add a "public:" there, and it is a public _block_ - this provokes a clear structure (opposed to langs. where members _separately_ have visibility/access declared (which is the reason why I _do_ use #regions there :))

Answer (score 12):

I think you can do this:

Reformat your someclass.cpp

```
namespace ns
{
  CClass::CClass() {}
  CClass::~CClass() {}
  void CClass::Test() {}
  void CClass::Test2() {}
  void CClass::Test3() {}
}
```

for example as

```
namespace ns // construction-destruction
{
  CClass::CClass() {}
  CClass::~CClass() {}
}
namespace ns // test-region
{
  void CClass::Test() {}
  void CClass::Test2() {}
  void CClass::Test3() {}
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Now we can do this by:

Right before the block that you want to fold you place the following define:

```
#define FOLDINGSTART {
```

and directly after the block you place:

```
#define FOLDINGEND }
```

Comment: This is probably the best solution for the problem that we have at the moment. The only problem is that you have to use a unique identifier for each region (otherwise you will receive a warning)

Answer (score 6):

you can place your code in {} and write a comment for its name.

```
{ // RegionName 
    void Test() {}
    void Test2() {}
    void Test3() {}
}
```

Comment: I second this over the rest

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old, I know, but it showed up when I myself was searching for a resolution to this problem so...

@ATatum_BlurPD said in [Qt Creator C++ folding region](/post/643395):

> I know this is old, but here is what works for me in QT Creator 4.13.3.
>
> - Make sure 'Display Folding markers' is enabled
>
>   - 'Tools' -> 'Options' -> 'Text Editor' -> 'Display' tab
> - In the '*.cpp' or '*.h' file you want to add the region to:
>
>   - Add '#pragma region *RegionNameHere*{'
>
>     - Note the '{' at the end
>   - Add '#pragma endregion }'
>
>     - Note the '}' at the end
>
> #### Some sample code:
>
> ```
> #pragma region TIMER:Filter Change Delay {
>
> void CLog_EntryList::init_Timer_FilterChangeDelay()
> {
>     m_timerFilterChangeDelay.setInterval(5000);
>     m_timerFilterChangeDelay.setSingleShot(true);
>     connect(&m_timerFilterChangeDelay, &QTimer::timeout, this, &CLog_EntryList::slot_Timer_FilterChangeDelay_Timedout);
> }
>
> void CLog_EntryList::slot_Timer_FilterChangeDelay_Start()
> {
>     if(m_timerFilterChangeDelay.isActive())
>         return;
>     
>     m_timerFilterChangeDelay.setInterval(5000);
>     m_timerFilterChangeDelay.setSingleShot(true);
>     m_timerFilterChangeDelay.start();
> }
>
> void CLog_EntryList::slot_Timer_FilterChangeDelay_Timedout()
> {
>     
> }
> #pragma endregion}
> ```

I don't have enough reputation here to post image-proof, but you can see them [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/112181/qt-creator-c-folding-region/15)

Answer (score 1):

This is very old but still actual.
For convenience, you can also **add a snippet** to automate entering a region of code.
Navigate menu to Preferences/Text Editor/Snippets, choose the group 'Text' and insert a new snippet having Trigger = region and Trigger Variant = name, then add the following text in the lower area (add an extra carriage return after the '}'). Now, in code, you can just type 'region' and the snippet will be inserted while the editor will ask to set the 'name' of the region.
Only drawback, #pragma region generates a warning but you can suppress it by adding:

`QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON += -Wno-unknown-pragmas`

to your .pro file. Anyway you can always substitute the snippet with whatever you find works better.

```
#pragma region $name$ {

#pragma endregion }
```

[Set Preferences...Snippet example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T9p5.png)

Answer (score 1):

It works this way:

```
#pragma region REGION1 {

// YOUR CODE

#pragma endregion REGION1 }
```

Comment: Welcome, another user had already answered the same. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58108447/356726

Answer (score 0):

you can place your code in {} and write a comment for its name.

This WILL THROW `"EXPECTED UN-QUALIFIED ID"` error.