# Code folding for condtional derivatives(#ifdefine) in Qt creator

Tags: qt-creator, code-folding

Is there a way to enable folding-marker for a code block surrounded by "conditional derivative" in Qt-Creator? I checked an [old link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295361/code-folding-pragma-region-in-qt-creator), where it says it's not possible but it was back in 2012. My Qt Creator version is 3.6.1 and an example code is given below.

```
#define DEBUG

#ifdef DEBUG
    // Print some statements.
#endif
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Qt creator 4.8.1 still can't do code folding for conditional derivatives!

Of course you can use braces {} inside #ifdef

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG
{
    ...
}
#endif
```

But this will add unsightly additional indent for code.
So I suggest to use braces this way:

```
#ifdef QT_DEBUG {
...
#else } {
...
#endif }
```

But this unfortunately will produced several warnings: "extra tokens at end of #ifdef/#endif directives".

Last one (for #endif) can be disabled with -Wno-endif-labels (add QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Wno-endif-labels to .pro file).
There is no such disabling warning option for #ifdef, so if this warning really annoys you, you in the end can use braces this way:

```
#ifndef QT_DEBUG
#else {
...
#endif }
```